# Compose parts, even if one export fails

Tags: c#, mef

I have the problem that I want to import types from a module dictionary. But because of the plugin based modularity some imports may fail.

But if only one import fails, nothing gets imported - which is certainly not wanted.

```
try
{
    // Use the binary directory
    var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(AssemblyDirectory);
    var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

    // Build the composition batch
    var compositionBatch = new CompositionBatch();
    compositionBatch.AddPart(this);                     // for discovering modules

    // Compose everything   
    container.Compose(compositionBatch);
}
catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException loadException)
{
    // Nothing will be done here
}
```

The correct and wanted behavior would be, that all matching types shall be imported, but the failing gets ignored.

How can I accomplish that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: [You can ignore failures at the assembly level](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4024372/1002306), would that be good enough?

Comment: That would be great. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12941480/1002306) has an example of how to ignore failed assemblies. You get a list of the assemblies from the directory you're using, and then create an AssemblyCatalog for each, force the error as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4024372/1002306), and then place the catalogs that didn't fail into an AggregateCatalog.